# Highcharts {Pie} - Change dataLabels connector curve

Tags: highcharts

How can I change the Highchart's dataLabel's connector curve as below?

> **`[Online Demo][1]`**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can control this behavior by setting `softConnector` to `false`.

```
plotOptions: {
            pie: {
                dataLabels: {
                    softConnector: false
                }
            }
        },
```

`softConnector: true` : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-softconnector-true/)

`softConnector: false` : [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/plotoptions/pie-datalabels-softconnector-false/)